# dynamic resistance of PN junction diode

Tags: diodes

I am lost here, I was wondering what voltages do I have to include in the equation that is asked for both v1 and v2? and how do I do that? [image]

Comment: The question is asking you to express the value of \$r_{ac}\$ with respect to \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$, and \$R_x\$. It already gives you the equation for \$r_{ac}\$, now express the variables in that equation in terms of those three.

Comment: What is the component that is in series with resistor \$R\$ and voltage source E ??

Comment: that's an ammeter, so Vt=V1+V2 ?

Comment: How do I add Rx into that equations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this question:

Assume that: $$R >> r_{ac}$$ This is a reasonable assumption if E >> the threshold voltage of the diode.

V2 = only the AC component of the voltage measurement

$$r_{ac} = \frac{v_{ac}}{i_{ac}} = \frac{V_2}{\frac{V_1}{R_x + r_{ac}}}$$

$$r_{ac} = V_2.\frac{(R_x + r_{ac})}{V_1}$$

$$r_{ac}.V_1 = V_2.(r_{ac} + R_x)$$

$$r_{ac}.V_1 = r_{ac}.V_2 + R_x.V_2$$

$$r_{ac} = \frac{V_2.R_x}{(V_1 - V_2)}$$